# Facebook API reading comments attachments

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

My trying to find a way to read all comments attachments. 
This is what my status update looks like: http://screencast.com/t/sXqOzA3OsF
There's an attachment with the message "Mitt Bidrag".

I'm getting the correct json-stream using "me/feed" but it's missing information about the attachment.
This is what the feed looks like: http://screencast.com/t/sEL2iEsVOWu

I've tried a bunch of FQL-commands with the comment/attachment-table but I'm only retreiving.
Here are some examples of what I've tried:

```
- SELECT id, text, time, fromid FROM comment WHERE object_id='100002055769071_617700241641829' AND parent_id='0' 
 - SELECT id, text, time, fromid FROM comment WHERE object_id='617700241641829_653988868012966' AND parent_id='0'
 - SELECT post_id, user_id FROM like WHERE post_id = "617700241641829_653988868012966"
 - SELECT message FROM stream WHERE post_id = "617700241641829_653988868012966"

Response is: {
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

Anyone have a solution?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it:

```
SELECT attachment FROM comment WHERE id="617700241641829_653988868012966"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use this FQL query to get the comment details based on post ID:

```
SELECT id, text, post_id, comment_count, attachment.media.image.src
FROM comment
WHERE post_id = "617700241641829_653988868012966"
```

Please refer [Comment-columns](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/) for more others comment details that you need to use.
Hope this can help to solve your problem.

Comment: This FQL solved it. SELECT attachment FROM comment WHERE id="617700241641829_653988868012966". Thank alot for your reply!

Comment: You are welcome. FYI, in the attachment has lot more. you can select 'attachment' but only or if u need more specific things just put '.' after attachment and what is the specific thing that u needed. refer this for references : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/